# How to implement a summation from 1 to infinite in python

Tags: python, limit, infinity

I'd like to calculate an infinite sum

Like this: Sum from k=1 to infinite of (0.9^k) * r + k+1 //or any other

My first idea was something like this:

```
def infiniteCalc(r):
    result = r
    for k in range(10000000):
        result += 0.9**k + r + k +1 +1 //k is starting at 0, so another +1

    return result
```

Another idea was to check, if the result changes within an iteration, but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Another idea was to use something like limit, but I don't know if python provides a function for that (and if, is this really my solution?)

Comment: What's your expected output? `sum( [1, inf) )` (that's set notation there, not python code) is...?

Comment: That series doesn't converge, so `return float('inf')`.

Comment: Minor fix, in order for it to work properly, instead of adding the extra +1, change `range(10000000)` to `range(1,10000000)`

Comment: [There is the `1/(0.1)` formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Comment: If you really want to do the sum and not use SymPy, then you should probably go for `itertools.count` which will continue indefinitely (so you need to break out of the for loop).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your objective is to do symbolic execution of expressions, rather than actually wanting to compute it numerically. For this you want a library like [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html). Here's the reference on summations: http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.summations.Sum

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using SymPy with your expression:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('r k')
(r, k)
>>> Sum((0.9**k) * r + k + 1,(k,1,oo))
Sum(0.9**k*r + k + 1, (k, 1, oo))
>>> _.doit()
Sum(0.9**k*r + k + 1, (k, 1, oo))
>>> nsimplify(_, rational=True)
Sum((9/10)**k*r + k + 1, (k, 1, oo))
>>> _.doit()
9*r + oo
```